# How to solve Yosemite massive memory leak?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, memory, memory-leak

I am experiencing a massive memory leak in Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C2513). I have 16 GB of RAM and the used memory rise to circa 15 GB in ~3 hours. Top applications usage is relatively low, circa 200 MB per application (10 top applications).

I solved it only shutting down the system.

Is there any update for this?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of Activity Monitor -> Memory

Comment: OS X (and all modern operating systems) is designed to use all of the memory that's available, for file caches if it has no better use for it. That's not a problem, since memory used for file caches is still available for applications to use. In Activity Monitor, what are the values for App Memory, File Cache, Wired Memory and Compressed?

Comment: @MikeScott I think You can post it as an answer. RAM is there to be used, You paid for it :)

Comment: Did you notice any performance or usability issues due to this memory situation?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I wrote it as an answer, but I changed it to a comment since it asks for more data. If the data support it, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Mh, maybe I misunderstood Activity Monitor - my fault. I read Memory Used and I thought it was the app memory. Indeed, App Memory is only ~7GB, while the most part is File Cache. I think I am going to delete this question.

Comment: @fbrundu You should leave the question here, so that the next person who does the same thing can find it, and the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OS X (and all modern operating systems) is designed to use all of the memory that's available, for file caches if it has no better use for it. That's not a problem, since memory used for file caches is still available for applications to use.